# Removing the inline-block margin that appears from empty divs

Tags: html, css, margin

I have three empty divs and one div with content.
The empty divs for some reason contain a margin that I can't adjust using `margin: 0;`.

How come I get the top and bottom margin of the empty divs displayed in the pictures?

```css
.widget-user-p{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 255px;
    min-height: 320px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #F4F4F4;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #CACACA;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.widget-user-empty{
    min-height: 1px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-user-p"></div>
<div class="widget-user-p widget-user-empty"></div>
<div class="widget-user-p widget-user-empty"></div>
<div class="widget-user-p widget-user-empty"></div>
```

**And this is the page output (notice the three lines has a margin between them):**

[image: website output]

Comment: I am not getting you really....

Comment: @BhojendraNepal What is is that is unclear?

Comment: you have added min-height as 1px so it is taking height make it 0 it may not take additional space

Comment: Basically, divs are by default `display: block` and not `inline` or `inline-block`. Why do you set them to `inline-block`? If you want them to sit one next to each other, use `float`. Block elements don't have spaces between them.

Comment: @Narxx I dont always want them to be next to each other. I want them to automatically adjust depending on the space surrounding them. I dont want them to be either beneath each other or next to each other. I want the empty divs to have 0 margin, so that they dont make the parent div bigger than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the given below code snippet. you have to remove space between div's.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
div{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div></div><!--
--><div></div><!--
--><div>dasdas</div>
```

Comment: There can't be space between them. Its being output like this `$count = 0;
        while($count < 3){
            $user_output .= '<div class="widget-user-p widget-user-empty"></div>';
            $count ++;
        }`

Comment: @GjertIngarGjersund actual the space is inline element space. It's not a margin. so when you are setting div's inline-block space will come by default. so you have to delete by your self or by commenting.

Comment: can you show me the full code @GjertIngarGjersund

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.

Removing the "invisible" margin of `inline-block` divs can be done using `font-size: 0;` on the parent element.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)